# get data from select option field and set comma separate format using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have one table with select list box. My requirement is when I hit submit button, get present data from select option list and display the value with comma separate format.

Here I attached the image file for your references.

[image]

In this case I hit submit button the data should display like {**d:d,sdf:sdf,d:d**}.

The Demo page : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FH2HM/)

Note: In my page I have add `button` which will add one more `<tr></tr>` when ever I want. so Its dynamic.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$("#ok").on("click", function(){
    var output = [],
        $selects = $("#s select"),
        i;
    for (i=0; i < $selects.length; i += 2)
        output.push($selects.eq(i).find("option:selected").text() + ":" +
                    $selects.eq(i+1).find("option:selected").text());

    var outputString = "{" + output.join(",") + "}";
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FH2HM/1/

That is, loop through the selects by twos, getting the `.text()` value of the selected options in each  pair and putting that pair into an array. Then after the loop join the array elements into a string separating by commas.

Note that if the values you want to display were in the option element's `value` property it would make the code simpler, because the line in the loop would be:

```
output.push($selects.eq(i).val() + ":" + $selects.eq(i+1).val());
```

Note that because this code loops through all the selects in the table it will automatically handle any dynamically added rows.

Comment: Hi, I need one more help please. I need to do this in reverse process from `output` value set back in to select list options. I have created one more questions in stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572629/comma-seperate-fiels-set-to-select-list-field can you please answer it....